# Odoo : How to display the "Force Availability" by dynamically?

Tags: xpath, odoo-8

I'm trying to display the "Force Availability" dynamically when SO Transfering. I did as following, but not working. How do I do?

```
def fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=None, view_type='form', context=True, toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    result = super(StockPicking, self).fields_view_get(cr, uid, view_id, view_type, context, toolbar, submenu)
    if view_type == 'form':
        obj_so_settings = self.pool.get('sale.config.settings')
        so_config_ids = obj_so_settings.search(cr, uid, [], limit=1, order='id DESC', context=context)
        if so_config_ids:
            so_settings = obj_so_settings.browse(cr, uid, so_config_ids[0], context=context)

        if so_settings.remove_force_availability:
            result.update({'arch': result['arch']
                                   + '<xpath expr="//button[@name=\'force_assign\']" position="attributes">'
                                     '<attribute name="invisible">1</attribute></xpath>'})
        else:
            pass

    return result
```

result['arch'] is holding the whole stock_picking form data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I got it

```
from lxml import etree
def fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=None, view_type=False, context=None, toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    if not context:
        context = {}
    res = super(custom_stock_pick, self).fields_view_get(cr, uid, view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, context=context, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)

    if view_type == 'form':
        remove_force_availability = False
        so_settings_obj = self.pool.get('sale.config.settings')
        so_config_ids = so_settings_obj.search(cr, uid, [], limit=1, order='id DESC', context=context)
        if so_config_ids:
            so_settings = so_settings_obj.browse(cr, uid, so_config_ids[0], context=context)
            remove_force_availability = so_settings.group_remove_force_availability

        if remove_force_availability:
            if res['name'] == 'stock.picking.form':
                doc = etree.fromstring(res['arch'])
                nodes = doc.findall(".//*[@name='force_assign']")

                for node in nodes:
                    parent = node.getparent()
                    parent.remove(node)
                    res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)
    return res
```